# Accessing spreadsheet in Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications, typeerror

I am writing a google script on top of a spreadsheet.
I want to deploy it as a web app.
It shows some values.
Unfortunately, with my current code, google reminds me:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getSheetByName" of null.

I have no idea where the mistake is.

Here's the code

```
function doGet(e) {
    var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Details');
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
    var dataFromCell = ss.getRange("B4").getValue();

    var mypanel = app.createVerticalPanel();
    var label = app.createLabel(dataFromCell);

    app.add(mypanel);
    app.add(label);

    return app;
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In standalone webapps you cannot use getActiveSpreadsheet because no one is using it actively...
Use `SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID')` instead, you can get the ID in the url of your spreadsheet like in this example :

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3d-------nZIV0JQQ0c1a3dWX1dQbGc#gid=0
```

between `key=` and `#`, ie `0AnqSFd3iikE3d-------nZIV0JQQ0c1a3dWX1dQbGc`

Comment: :) "If you are unsure then why downvote my answer? Please reconsider... " oh my god

Comment: I think this answer can be true .

Comment: Note that the URL structure has changed: _For example, the spreadsheet ID in the URL https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abc1234567/edit#gid=0 is `"abc1234567"`._

Comment: reference for document id http://alicekeeler.com/2013/08/03/google-docs-unique-id/

Comment: var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID') ;  but ss.getUi is not valid. If you know the id how to you get the UI?

Comment: The spreadsheet UI can't be accessed in this context. "open" does not mean "show in browser", it means "open for read and write"...

Answer (score 3):

Not need to use ID , just try this code ( change mygooglelocation with your Spreadsheet name and range of cells. Working very well for me with google maps...

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('mygooglelocation');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var mylocationInfo   = ss.getRange("A2:B4").getValues();
```

Comment: I'm afraid you misunderstood the question... this was about webapps that run independently of the spreadsheet in a doGet/return structure. If you want to prove your point please show a full example.

Comment: then will be my mistake ... I saw many errors on internet about getRange(...).getValue() and I suppose it's same problem...

Comment: "Your vote are locked unless your answer is edited..." i try to edit to give back you the vote but I don't let me even I add comment ...

Comment: No worries... 7 was a nice number but 6 is not bad after all. :-)