# JDBC Reading from a Database... TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 9)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am hoping someone can assist me in getting the JDBC script Reading from a Database example here... https://developers.google.com/apps-script/jdbc ...to work with my db.

```
    function foo() {
      var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://<host>:3306/<instance>", "user", "password");
      var stmt = conn.createStatement();
      stmt.setMaxRows(100);
      var start = new Date();
      var rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from clients");

      var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var cell = doc.getRange('a1');
      var row = 0;
      while(rs.next()) {
        cell.offset(row, 0).setValue(rs.getString(1));
        cell.offset(row, 1).setValue(rs.getString(2));
        cell.offset(row, 2).setValue(rs.getString(3));
        cell.offset(row, 3).setValue(rs.getString(4));
        row++;
      }
      rs.close();
      stmt.close();
      conn.close();
      var end = new Date();
      Logger.log("time took: " + (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
    }
```

I plugged in my server and user info and changed the select * statement to the table "clients" in my db. Connection is successful but I get the following error...

**TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 9)**

The table "clients" in my db has the following columns...

```
     id, clientname, clientcontact, clientphone, clientnote
```

Can someone help me understand what needs to be changed in the example script for it to work with my clients table? I am not a programmer by far... but I would like to get this working and use it as a template to get data from mysql into google spreadsheets so I can then publish the sheet on my google site.

Thanks!

Comment: The error message says that the variable 'doc' is null... are you running this script from within a spreadsheet ?

(sorry if my question seems trivial but I can't be sure without asking)

Comment: No I'm running the script by opening it directly in my Drive. I created the script in Drive and saved it. I then went to insert the script into a spreadsheet I created named "mysqltest" but i dont see my script in the gallery, i only see scripts others have created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script is supposed to run from a spreadsheet container or at least to have access to a spreadsheet to write its results.

So you have 2 possibilities:

1. Copy /paste your script in the spreadsheet script editor and run it from there.
2. Replace the spreadsheetApp.getActive with openbyId(spreadsheet id)
    (See [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990637/accessing-spreadsheet-in-google-script/12990713#12990713) for more information) your are indeed in almost the same situation since your script is not directly related to the spreadsheet it uses.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I used the openbyid(spreadsheet id) as suggested and the code is now working without error and is populating the test sheet!

Comment: This was indeed probably the best choice... (at least the one I 'd choose too! ) glad it helped :-)

Comment: Thanks Serge.  Yep, that openbyid was the cure!  I was calling it from a timer trigger, so obviously no active spreadsheet!  Which explains why it was working when I had it open in debug mode but not running stand-alone in "prod".